# Java Timestamp - How can I create a date and time string with the timestamp 1420432787?

Tags: java, android

How can I create a date and time string with the timestamp  1420432787 which is equal to 1/05/2015 10:09:47.

Bellow code is also not working

```
 Date date = new Date(1420432787);
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:a");
 System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

result of this  1/17/1970 10:34 AM

Comment: It should be like this Date date = new Date(1420451151811);

Comment: You say 1420451151811 in your question, but use 1420432787 in your code. Which one is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Rathode : Check online millisecond to date from http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm ... Where does you are getting the millisecond ? Is this millseconds are correct ?

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Date constructor accepts the time as **long in milliseconds, not seconds**.

You need to multiply it by 1000 and make sure that you supply it as long.

```
Date date = new Date(timeInSeconds * 1000);
```

then you can parse it into your date format

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:a");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: I have tried with new Date(timeInSeconds * 1000) but still geting wrong output and my timeInSeconds var in sec.

Comment: @Rathore timeInSeconds should be a long variable, if you want to use the seconds directly then you can 'write Date date = new Date(1420432787L * 1000)'